# How to add watermark to every page using mpdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I'm using `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` package in laravel to generate a pdf. In this code i added watermark but that watermark is coming only on the last page though i wanted that to be in every page.

```
$pdf = PDFm::loadHtml($result->document);
$pdf->mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
$pdf->mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
return $pdf->download('hdtuto.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, it should work. Could you however, give the following a try?

```
$config = ['instanceConfigurator' => function($mpdf) {
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
}]

PDF::loadHtml($result->document, $config)->download('hdtuto.pdf');
```

In this case, we are initialising the `PDF` instance with the right configuration instance, instead of doing it after loading the HTML.

Comment: Awesome bro. I got a perfect solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting/marking it if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

mPDF [doc](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setwatermarktext.html) states that

> The watermark will be added to each page when the Footer is printed if the variable $showWatermark is set to 1 or true.

Try to add header/footer to your PDF and set corresponding flags

Answer (score 0):

If any one trying to use blade file instead of direct html document, you can use view function which will return html content to the loadHtml method.

```
$config = ['instanceConfigurator' => function($mpdf) {
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
}]

$pdf = PDF::loadHtml(view('path.to.blade_file', $blade_data), $config);

return $pdf->stream('DocumentName.pdf');
```

**if you want to use an image as watermark**

```
$config = ['instanceConfigurator' => function ($mpdf) {
                $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage(asset('path/to/image_file'));
                $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
                // $mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.2; // image opacity 
                // dd($mpdf) // show all attributes 
            }];

            $pdf = PDF::loadHtml(view('path.to.blade_file', $blade_data), $config);

            return $pdf->stream('DocumentName.pdf');
```